# Derivative of a summation w.r.t. inside term

Tags: derivatives

My question is close to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289989/first-and-second-derivative-of-a-summation) except for one term. More specifically:

$$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i = 1}^m (x_i - \mu)^2$$

If I wanted to find the derivative of this entire term w.r.t. $x_i - \mu$, how would I go about that? Is this even possible?

**Edit**

I've tried the derivation but I'm not sure if this is correct. I also left out an important detail that in this context $\mu = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i = 1}^m x_i$ (i.e. the mean of $x$'s).

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \sum}{\partial (x_i - \mu)} \left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i = 1}^m(x_i - \mu)^2\right) & = \frac{\partial \sum}{\partial (x_i - \mu)} \frac{1}{m}\left((x_1 - \mu)^2 + \cdots + (x_m - \mu)^2\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{m}\left(2(x_1 - \mu) + \cdots + 2(x_m - \mu)\right) \\
& = \frac{2}{m}\left( (x_1 + \cdots + x_m) - 2m\mu\right) \\
& = 2\left( \dfrac{1}{m} \cdot (x_1 + \cdots + x_m) -  \dfrac{1}{m} \cdot 2m\mu \right) \\
& = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i = 1}^m x_i - 4\mu \\
& = 2\mu - 4\mu \\
& = -2\mu
\end{align}
$$

I'm not entirely sure if this derivation is correct...

Answer (score 1):

- Rename your variables (for example $t_i = x_i - \mu$). So yes, you can differentiate with respect to $t_i$.
- Result
  $$
  \frac{2}{m} \left( x_i - \mu \right)
  $$